# How to push only some branches of git

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I created laravel project. I am trying various concepts in laravel. to keep concept code seprated from each other I uses branching. I created branches as auth,multiauth, orm-onetomany orm-onetoone, orm-many-many. I just want to push  orm-onetomany orm-onetoone, orm-many-many and ignore auth & multiauth. How can I do this..??

Comment: Hi Pramod, welcome to SO. So your question is "How to do that *in one command*?" I guess. I assume you don't want to just checkout and push each one in turn.

Comment: Just use `git push <remotename> <branchnames>`.

Answer (score 3):

Pushing multiple refs is fine. Just list them

```
git push <remoteName> orm-onetomany orm-onetoone orm-many-many
```

If you're likely to do that often, make an alias (arbitrary name *ppp* here but choose anything you prefer)

```
git config --global alias.ppp 'push <remoteName> orm-onetomany orm-onetoone orm-many-many'

# then later just
git ppp
```